# Remove new lines from data retrived from text file using PHP

Tags: php

I have following data in text file

```
375020222511963
284970411563422
290245594366931
```

I need to retrieve a random variable from the above text file.

I use the following php code to do that

```
<?php 
    $file = file("file.txt");
    $len = count($file);
    $rand  = rand ( 0, $len-1 );
    echo $file[$rand];
?>
```

But it's returning new line along with the retrieved data. I need to retrieve data without new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change last line to:

```
echo trim($file[$rand]);
```

**[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** removes white-spaces (blanks, new lines, tabs) from the beginning and end of a string.

In order to avoid empty lines... If the last line is always the only empty one:

```
$rand = rand (0, $len - 2); // Instead of -1
```

Else, if you can have empty lines everywhere, replace the last two lines of code with:

```
do {
    $rand  = rand (0, $len - 1);
} while (trim($file[$rand]) == '');

echo $file[$rand];
```

Comment: NULL? Are you sure? The array is filled with lines read from the file. Elements can be null only if you try to access out of boundaries (for example, if you do `$file[3]` on a three lines file). `trim()` never returns NULL.

Comment: null in the sense empty value sir

Comment: Do you have any empty lines in your files? Maybe the last line in an empty one?

Comment: yea...last line is always empty i guess.the text file is not static ..values are added each time using 
file_put_contents('file.txt', $someValue.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

Answer (score 6):

The [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function has an optional second argument taking a [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) of flags which affect what is returned in the array.

Available flags are `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH`, `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, and `SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`.  The `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is the one that you want to use in order to have each line in the array **not** include the trailing newline character.

So, your line of code should look like the following.

```
    $file = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Descriptions and more info, see http://php.net/file.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks :)